Chrome driver version (126) - can't find the chromedriver.exe
My Chrome version is 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (64-bit).
But I can not find the related driver I tried with.
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable
The last number of version is 127 that it make this issue hard.

For an easy fix use Wayback Machine you'll find the 126 driver there.
Here is the link for your convenience:
Cheers!

Are you using the thing that automatically gets the latest chrome driver? For me, I'm using python
  from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager def setUp(self): chrome_options = Options() chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu') self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
For me, changing from using ChromeDriverManager().install() to "c:\windows\chromedriver.exe" path of the latest stable chrome worked.
Oddly enough, this was the latest stable at
https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/126.0.6478.126/win64/chromedriver-win64.zip
It says version 126.0.6478.126, and my chrome is version 126.0.6478.127, but it works when I don't rely on chrome manager. It honestly seems like chrome manager is the problem, or maybe there's something wrong with the API it relies on.

Chrome is up to date
Version 126.0.6478.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) and 3days a go up date as a rule they role out every Tues some twice f there a bug Glitch they send a update fix  almost 2 weeks nothing for me .nothing wrong with my pc  device and in services it's turned on to recieve updates.

it's on there not our's hope this helps

It doesn't look like this is of much help for the poster of the question. Check your spelling and interpunction, your text is hard to understand.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

C:\Windows\system32>npx @puppeteer/browsers install chromedriver@126.0.6478.127

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable
first column indicates if it is the browser or the driver, second column is the platform.
Scroll down and look for the one that works for you
It worked for me...

Chrome driver v126 is now available
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/#stable
If in future, you didn't find the version you are looking for? Simply change the version number in the zip download URL.
Sometimes if it doesn't work for the exact version number, you can find the nearest version by trail and error
Thanks
